# Unity WebGL - icall not supported by IL2CPP

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl, il2cpp

I'm on a WebGL project that uses MongoDB. I have all the MongoDB assemblies and dependencies.

I can build the project fine & run it but then I get this error:

`Build.framework.js.br:3  NotSupportedException: C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2021.3.24f1/Editor/Data/il2cpp/libil2cpp/icalls/mscorlib/System.Reflection/RuntimeModule.cpp(101) : Unsupported internal call for IL2CPP:Module::GetPEKind - "This icall is not supported by il2cpp."`

I know that it is related to the MongoDB driver.
After some tests, I found that the error happens with the call `new MongoClient(ConnectionString)`;

I'm using Unity 2021.3.24f1 on Windows 10.

Thank you !

Comment: Suggests that mongodb isnt webgl compatible. Doesnt sound too surprising